# Как в jQuery Validate Plagin сделать проверку типа "любое из двух полей, или оба"?

Tags: jquery, валидация

На странице используется jQuery Validate Plagin для проверки полей на заполнение. Есть два поля - телефон и e-mail. Как сделать проверку таким образом, чтобы можно было заполнить или телефон, или e-mail, или оба поля?